# How to combine two excel sheets together

Tags: excel, combinations

I got two .csv files with the exact same column and row annotations.
They differer in the values in the sheets.

I want to combine these sheets into one sheet, adding all the values.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: The most basic solution, if the columns are identical, is to combine the two files in a text editor, removing the header row in the second file... or is there something else that needs to be done? Python has a CSV module that may help you too.

Answer (score 1):

Open it up in notepad, remove the headers and copy paste the one below the other. Take extra care not to leave any additional space in the file. You can verify that it is ok by opening it up in excel afterwards.

Comment: I want to end up with a file identical with the sheets, just with the values added together. Will your method make this happen?

Comment: Ah you mentioned adding. I would again do that in excel. Open the two csv files, Use tab to columns if necessary to see the data better. then open a new Excel sheet and at the first row-column add the two relative sheets row columns from the csv files e.g =sheet1!A1+Sheet2!A2. Drag to the left and to the bottom as necessary so as to get all the results. At the end. copy the data only from the third sheet and paste as values on one of the initial sheets. Save using save as so as not to replace the initial sheet. Hope this helps.